# How to run Flutter web from within Android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, google-chrome, flutter-web

I am able to launch my app with iOS / Android emulators as one would expect, but not with Chrome.

Here's my run config:

[image]

And for some reason I'm getting the "No Connected Devices Found" error:

[image]

How can this be fixed?

---

I've tried `flutter config --enable-web`, but the problem persists.

`flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

`flutter devices` output:

```
1 connected device:

Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110
```

Comment: Does `flutter run -d chrome` from terminal work?

Comment: strangely, yes, it does

Comment: I don't use Android Studio, but in VSCode you can create a `launch.json` file that is used when you start debugging from VSCode, and there you can specify options for starting in Chrome.

Comment: If you are interested I can share what parameters I have in `launch.json` for Chrome.

Comment: `launch.json` does essentially the same thing as the [run configuration dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPSXt.png) above, so this should be working..

Comment: This is what I have, I also added and option to use a fix port: `{"name": "Web", "request": "launch", "type": "dart", "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}", "args":["-d", "chrome", "--web-port=51975"]}`.

Comment: Tried to add the port, but same thing

Comment: Sorry, no other idea.

Comment: That's ok, thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

Use the flutter devices command, you should see chrome as a device. In the device list of Android studio, it will show you the option to run your project on the web. you can do the same using the command line too. **Use flutter run -d chrome command** to run your project on the web.

Comment: What do you mean by "device list of Android studio"? Also, I am aware that I can run the project through the command line (which I currently do), but I want it to be launched by the Android Studio

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can add some code in here. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.